# How to re-enable internet access after sending an AccessReject in a RADIUS server?

Tags: network-programming, freeradius, radius

I'm working with a RADIUS server that's linked to a control device. I have the ability to deny Internet access by sending an AccessReject to the control device.

The issue I face is after denying Internet access, I want to re-enable it, but I'm unsure how to command the control device to permit Internet access once again.

I've been considering the use of Change of Authorization (CoA) requests to accomplish this. Is this a viable solution? Is there another method or approach that might work in this situation?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If more information about my setup is needed to provide a suitable answer, I'd be more than happy to provide additional details.

Thanks in advance for your help!